# How to show files copy progress

Tags: python

I want to copy large amount of big files from folder A to folder B.

I have 2 option in Python.

[shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

[Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) with subprocess

```
import subprocess
command = "ROBOCOPY {} {} /MOVE /E".format(src, dst)
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

When I used above methods my Python IDE do copy operation blindly.

Is there some way I can show the file copy progress.

Comment: "my python IDE do copy operation blindly." What do you mean by that?

Comment: Did you search for  "python copy progress bar"?

Comment: I  want to avoid adding prints in my code.

Comment: i am not looking for a progress bar ..can we display the copy output in a command prompt window ..?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the completed copy output, yes we can. Here is the code for that.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
cmd = r'ROBOCOPY {} {} {}'.format('D:\\TF1','D:\\TF2','license.xml')
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stderr=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
a = p.communicate()
for i in a:
   print i
```

and the output will be as follows

```
  Started : Thu Jun 02 16:12:09 2016

   Source : D:\TF1\
   Dest : D:\TF2\

   Files : license.xml

  Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                   1    D:\TF1\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Bytes :     1.7 k         0     1.7 k         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

   Ended : Thu Jun 02 16:12:09 2016
```

Are you expecting something like this?
P.S: The actual output is much cleaner.